# Javascript: Create 2 dimensional array from array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, arrays

I have the following array of objects and want to have a 2d array from it.
What I have tried so far :

```
let arr = [
  {
    "id": '1',
    "userId": '1',
    "postId": 1,
    "type": 'like'
  },
  {
    "id": '2',
    "userId": '1',
    "postId": 2,
    "type": 'like'
  },
  {
    "id": '3',
    "userId": '2',
    "postId": 3,
    "type": 'like'
  },
  {
    "id": '4',
    "userId": '2',
    "postId": 4,
    "type": 'dislike'
  },
  {
    "id": '5',
    "userId": '2',
    "postId": 1,
    "type": 'disklike'
  },
];

var newArr = arr.map(function(val, index){          
 return [val.type]
})
```

This returns :

```
[
    ["like"], ["like"], ["like"], ["dislike"], ["dislike"]
]
```

Which is not the expected results, The expected results are :

```
[
    ["like", "like"], // User 1
    ["like", "dislike", "dislike"] // User 2
]
```

as user with `userId 1` have two likes and user with `userId 2` have one like and two dislikes.

What am I missing here.

Comment: Show us what you tried already and we will fix your work. But we are not here for writing your code ;)

Comment: @marks I have updated my question with my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```js
    const original = [
      {
        id: '1',
        userId: '1',
        postId: 1,
        type: 'like'
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        userId: '1',
        postId: 1,
        type: 'like'
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        userId: '2',
        postId: 3,
        type: 'like'
      }
    ];
    const newArray = original.reduce ((array, item) => {
      const index = parseInt(item.userId) - 1;
      array[index] = array[index] ?? [];
      array[index].push(item.type);
      return array;
    }, []);
    console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it doesn't creates the 2d array btw

Comment: @Grammer can you please run the code and let me know where it is different with your desired output?

Comment: yeah slightly different, see the question, the expect results needs to be a 2d array just having `like` and `dislike`, as there are two `userId` only and `userId 1` have two likes and `userId 2` have 1 like and 2 dislikes, I have mentioned expected array at the end of the question, thank you again.

Comment: like needs to 1 and dislike needs to be 0 in the returned/expected array.

Comment: see the updated question, it should make more sense now

Comment: The answer is updated now, but it is really confusing that the index of your desired array is the userId - 1. Since in your example the index 0 assigned to user 1 and index 1 is assigned to user 2